# sign apk using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: android, apk, signature, bitbucket-pipelines

it's my first time using bitbucket pipelines, I want to build an signed apk, I have the script, it generates the apk already, however, it seems there is something wrong on the signature, I've been trying to figure out why but I have had any success.

[image: bittbucket-pipelines.yml]

As you see on the script above, I'm generating the apk, I've created some repository variables to pass the signature data, so once the apk is ready, I use the following command to verify the apk signature :

**keytool -printcert -jarfile app-debug.apk**

[image: sinature apk verificator]

then I see the signature data does not match with the apk signed by the ide (using the same certificate,jks, passwords and alias)

I hope any of you can help me, thanks.

Comment: I fixed, the problem was that I did not use the signingConfigs, so I added the signingConfigs and now it's working, I would like to say I don't get the values from the project, I get the values from the ~./gradle/gradle.config

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, be sure you are correctly encoding/decoding your .jks file...

encode:

```
base64 -w 0 my_keystore_file_name.jks > envout.txt
```

copy the contents of `envout.txt` to `$DEBUG_STORE_FILE_BASE64` repository variable. Meaning you open envout.txt (in notepad or something) select all `ctrl+a` and copy `ctrl+c`

decode:

```
echo $DEBUG_STORE_FILE_BASE64 | base64 -d > my_keystore_file_name.jks
```

it may not matter, but `$DEBUG_STORE_FILE` should just be filename, and if you still have issues you could try to not use a secured repository variable, or move the file after its created:

```
mv $DEBUG_STORE_FILE keys/$DEBUG_STORE_FILE
```

or

```
cp $DEBUG_STORE_FILE keys/$DEBUG_STORE_FILE
```